# Arrow function for time delay plotting in R with Rstudio

Tags: r

I need a plot to show the position of a man walking randomly in four main direction. I use RStudio, and I'd like to see the positions as they are generated.
Walking outside the ranges is not allowed, (-L1,L1) for walking horizontally and (-L2,L2) for walking vertically. The problem is with 'arrow' function, when the man arrived at limitations, no arrows draws anymore.

```
   RW2<-function(n,L1,L2){
   plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="",xlim = c(-L1,L1),ylim = c(-L2,L2))
   text(0,0,"*")
   x<-y<-numeric(0)
   x[1]=y[1]=0
   for (i in 2:n){
     directtion<-sample(-1:1,1)
       if (directtion==0){
         x[i]<-x[i-1]
         ifelse((y[i-1]<=L2 && y>=-L2),y[i]<-y[i-1]+sample(c(-1,1),1),y[i]<-y[i-  1])
          }
      else {
         ifelse((x[i-1]<=L1 && x[i-1]>=-L1),x[i]<-x[i-1]+directtion,x[i]<-x[i-1])
         y[i]<-y[i-1]
         }
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
        arrows(x[i-1],y[i-1],x[i],y[i],length = 0.08,col =i)
          }
     }
RW2(100,5,5)
```

Thank you everyone in advance and sorry for my English writing.